# Riak Docs not working

Tags: riak, riak-ts

Can anyone tell why Riak website is not working this time from a few days.

http://docs.basho.com/riak/ts/1.5.2/using/core-fundamentals/

this link of riak is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Shahzad, Basho as a company doesn't really exist any more (https://www.theregister.co.uk/AMP/2017/07/31/end_of_the_road_for_basho_as_court_puts_biz_into_receivership/) so it might be related to that. If you are relying on resources provided by Basho you might want to make copies of those resources before they vanish forever.

**Update**: Looks like the resources have been acquired and everything will get open sourced soon. See: http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2017-August/019500.html

Answer (score 2):

We (my company) have hosted a mirror of the docs generated out of the basho_doc project. Feel free to use:

https://riak.docs.hw.ag/

Answer (score 1):

Riak documentation is still accessible via the [basho_doc](https://github.com/basho/basho_docs) GitHub repository.

And particularly the document you are looking for https://github.com/basho/basho_docs/blob/15a97f6a2c82f77e8248d5151171bd2f7b88e11b/content/riak/ts/1.5.2/using/core-fundamentals.md. It's not as nice as a Web page, but still readable.